# Wisconsin Renter Rights - Lease switching to month-to-month

Tags: rental-property, real-estate, residential-lease, wisconsin

I am currently in a lease in Wisconsin the lease states “ The Lease Agreement wil begin on May 1, 2023 and will end on April 28, 2024. “, as we are planning to move out at the end of this term (April 28th 2024) I called our landlord to ask about carpet cleaning, they responded to me, saying I must provide 60 day notice that I will be moving out, making the move out date May 29th 2024. The lease states - “ At the end of this Lease Agreement, this lease will continue in full force and effect on a month to month basis unless Tenet or Landlord provides written notice to the other party at least 60 days before the end of the term (Term of Lease Agreement) to terminate the Lease (including any exercised renewal or extension thereof).“ My question is is this even legal within Wisconsin? The state statute says 28 days notices(Wis. Stat. § 704.19), I have given 48 days.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, any laws or statutes I can show that support my case would be great.

Thank you